# How should I set a Boolean that will be available to all my app controllers?

Tags: ios, global-variables

I have a Help mode in my app that "tells" all the buttons to behave differently when the app is in help mode.

I wish to set a global boolean that will indicate if the app is in Help mode or not.

What is the Best practice for that ?

Thanks
Shani

Comment: NSUserDefault, or Singleton class.

Comment: or a property in your application's delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting it in the App Delegate, and then accessing it from that by:

```
AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
myAppDelegate.yourboolean = YES;
```

and go on that way. OR use an NSNotification. When your app goes into help mode set up an NSNotification in the view controller where the help mode is turned on.

```
//Put this right after the switch for help mode is turned on!

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"helpModeOn" object:yourboolean];
```

and in all the other view controllers or files that help mode affects should have this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ThingYouWantToDoWhenHelpModeIsOn:) name:@"helpModeOn" object:nil];
}

- (void)ThingYouWantToDoWhenHelpModeIsOn:(NSNotification *)notification{
        // Make sure you have an BOOL in your header file for all the other view controllers
        ThatBooleanValue = [notification object];
        [self performSelector:@selector(OtherThings:) object:ThatBooleanValue];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a global static Boolean and make it available as extern via some .h file. That is a perfectly acceptable way to do it in some cases.

If you want users to return to your app the way they left it, for example they are in Help mode now, leave and come back next day and still be in help mode, then I might do it using Preferences via NSUserDefaults.